# How to remove NA data in only one columns?

Tags: r

I have a file that looks like so:

```
date       A  B
2014-01-01 2  3
2014-01-02 5  NA
2014-01-03 NA NA
2014-01-04 7  11
```

If I use `newdata <- na.omit(data)` where `data` is the above table loaded via R, then I get only two data points.  I get that since it will filter all instances of NA.  What I want to do is to filter for each `A` and `B` so that I get three data points for `A` and only two for `B`.  Clearly, my main data set is much larger than that and the numbers are different but neither should not matter.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `is.na()` on the relevant vector of data you wish to look for and index using the negated result. For exmaple:

```
R> data[!is.na(data$A), ]
        date A  B
1 2014-01-01 2  3
2 2014-01-02 5 NA
4 2014-01-04 7 11
R> data[!is.na(data$B), ]
        date A  B
1 2014-01-01 2  3
4 2014-01-04 7 11
```

`is.na()` returns `TRUE` for every element that is `NA` and `FALSE` otherwise. To index the rows of the data frame, we can use this logical vector, but we want its converse. Hence we use `!` to imply the opposite (`TRUE` becomes `FALSE` and vice versa).

You can restrict which columns you return by adding an index for the columns after the `,` in `[ , ]`, e.g.

```
R> data[!is.na(data$A), 1:2]
        date A
1 2014-01-01 2
2 2014-01-02 5
4 2014-01-04 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Every column in a data frame must have the same number of elements, that is why `NA`s come in handy in the first place...

What you can do is

```
df.a <- df[!is.na(df$A), -3]
df.b <- df[!is.na(df$B), -2]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of Python we can use subset to define column/columns and inplace true is to make the changes in DF:-
rounds2.dropna(subset=['company_permalink'],inplace=True)