# Trouble removing NA from whole row but from just one column

Tags: r, na

I have a file which consists of 41 variables (columns), many of which contain NA values, therefore I only wish to remove the NA from one column (but remove the whole row which the NA is associated with) I have seen this answer [How to remove NA data in only one columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977972/how-to-remove-na-data-in-only-one-columns) and tried this, however it just does not seem to work. I get no error messages

Here is a snippet of my data:

dframe1 = my whole dataset, including 41 variables (columns) and 63 rows.

```
Trip_Set   Sex       Clasper.state
119_1      NA        NA
119_2      NA        NA
119_3      NA        NA
119_4      hembra    NA
119_4      hembra    NA
119_5      NA        NA
```

I wish to take away only the rows containing NAs from the sex column so that my data looks like this:

dframe2 = my new dataset, including 41 variables (columns) and however many rows sex has, minus the NA rows.

```
Trip_Set   Sex       Clasper.state
119_4      hembra    NA
119_4      hembra    NA
```

Here is the code from the question above which I have been trying to use:

```
#Taking NAs away from the sex column only

dframe2 <- dframe1[!is.na(dframe1$sex),]
```

Comment: did you close the square bracket?

Comment: oops, yes, sorry must have pasted incorrectly.

Comment: Look at my answer for the other possible mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(DataCombine)
DropNA(dframe1, Var = "Sex", message = F)
```

In your code I see two possible mistakes:

1) You didn't close the square bracket;

2) it should be `dframe1$Sex`, not `dframe1$sex` (remember that R is case-sensitive).

Comment: I have just tried this and again, get no error messages, but it just doesn't seem to remove the NAs in the column when I view the dataset afterwards - it is exactly the same. Is there something missing about the format of the NA? It is simply written in the CSV as NA - and listed as a factor when I check structure. Do I need to first convert the column or something?

Comment: strange. What's the output you get doing `lapply(dframe1, class)`?

Comment: oh and it's definitely 'sex' (lowercase - I just checked) and I did close the brackets, have edited question to reflect this.

Comment: please do `dput(dframe1)` and paste the output you get so that I can reproduce exactly what you have

Comment: OH MY! In doing this, I have just realised when importing my data, I was including dframe1<-read.table("Workbook1.csv",sep=",",header=T, na.strings=T)

Upon removing na.strings=T your method above works perfectly. THANKYOU for all of your help (and apologies)

Comment: I am supposing that perhaps the NAs are actually a level of your factor variable, so it would not be `NA` but `'NA'`.

Comment: Ok, so it is what I started to suppose. So do: `subset(dframe1, Sex != 'NA')`