# How to remove NA observations from a categorical Variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> DF <- data.frame(v = factor(c("red", "blue", "green", "blue",NA,NA,NA)))
> summary(DF)
     v    
 blue :2  
 green:1  
 red  :1 
 NA: 3
```

I have two questions: 1)How can i remove these NA from this categorical variable? I mean i want to remove all rows from my dataframe who have NA in v. (As My original dataframe has many columns). 
2)How can i remove "green" from this variable?

Comment: I don't see any `NA` values when I do `summary(DF)` . To remove them `NA` in general you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977972/how-to-remove-na-data-in-only-one-columns

Comment: I have edit my example. Now you can reproduce it.

Comment: I just want to remove NA from v.

Comment: `subset(DF, !is.na(v))`

Comment: Thanks and second part of my question. How to remove "green".

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your NAs. 
but in your original dataframe, you may want to perform:

```
DF<-na.omit(DF)
```

This should remove all the NAs.

Comment: I have edit the example. Now it is reproduecable. Moreover i want to remove all the rows having NA in column V.

Comment: The na.omit solution should work even then. Try it